# Dynamic installation and loading of Node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, module, npm

I am working on a Node.js module A that uses another Node.js module B from NPM. There are new versions of module B published on NPM. I want my module A to dynamically update to the latest versions of module B (module A always depends on the latest version of module B).Also, all the references of the imported module should also be updated dynamically.

I considered using NPM programmatically to install the latest available version of a module if a module is outdated. Are there better solutions to do this dynamically.

Also, how to forcefully update the module references imported through require?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least to the first part of your question (module A always using the latest version of module B), you could always specify the dependency in your `package.json` with a [major version wildcard](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning#semver-for-consumers):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "moduleB": "*"
  }
}
```

Which would then allow you to always `npm update` to the latest version. (This would, however, potentially have the effect of introducing changes that break backwards compatibility in your module as npm uses [Semantic Versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning).)

As for running `npm update` automatically, I have to ask - why is this necessary? What would be the benefit to users of your module? You should be, at the very least, "curating" updates to your dependencies to ensure no breaking changes are introduced. If you did set up a full automatic pipeline for updating dependencies (from `npm update`ing dependencies to `git tag`ing new versions to `npm version`ing these new versions to `npm publish`ing these new versions, for example), you're sort of leaving users of your module out in the cold should any of these steps break compatibility with their code.

(Also, if this automatic dependency updating *never* breaks your module, then what is your module adding? Is it even doing anything non-trivial with the dependencies?)

It might seem cumbersome, but it's a better practice to update your dependencies with some craft and intention. [See Semantic Versioning for more info.](http://semver.org/)

Comment: Thanks @wisew for the pointers! The reason why "npm update" needs to happen automatically is that 1. The module B will also be published by me 2. Updates to module B will be critical bug fixes. The idea is to abstract the frequently updated (with fixes) part of the ecosystem into a separate module and all other modules will have "dependency" on it. Module B will be curated before published to NPM. I want the consumers of module A to get the curated versions of Module B with critical fixes without their intervention.